# Why is does a timedelta command create an error on a different computer?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I'm currently working on two different computers, but running the exact same code on both computers leads on one of the two computers generating:

```
ValueError: cannot create timedelta string converter for [-1 days +23:05:00.000000000]
```

The error is caused by the command:

```
df_gt["Duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df_gt[ "Duration"])
```

And the df is created by an csv import via:

```
df_gt = pd.read_csv(gt_data, sep='\t', header=(0))
```

First, I thought the error was caused by the negative number. I have seen problems with negative numbers in the past, but this should have been the same problem on the other computer.

Then, I wondered if it might be caused by a different csv/time setting on this computer generating other formats, but when printing the value, I get exactly the same format(at least by visual inspection). I still think the problem is somewhere in this domain but I'm not sure how an other computer can effect this internal code.

Some hardware info:

The computer on which everything is working is running Windows 10 Home, and uses Pycharm Professional 2017.1. The other is running Windows 7 Professional sp 1 and uses Spyder 2.3.1. The code is in Python 3.

Thanks in advance,

Jeff

**EDIT:**

In the original question there was still

```
.total_seconds()
```

attached to the command, this was by mistake. (Just an attempt by my self to resolve this)

Comment: Is pandas version different in both PCs? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: Yes, the one on which is it not working runs 0.14.1 and the working one runs 0.20.1. Is there a significant difference between these versions? Unfortunately I can't upgrade the older pandas due to company regulations

Comment: I think there is problem, because 3 years is in active developed software huge difference. So try upgrade for remove all problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe need `.dt`:

```
df_gt["Duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df_gt[ "Duration"]).dt.total_seconds()
```

It seems different versions of pandas, so oldiest version is buggy.

Version `0.14.1` was released [July 11 2014](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-14-1-july-11-2014).

Version `0.20.1` was released [May 5 2017](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-20-1-may-5-2017).

Comment: Thanks, so that would mean that if I can't update my pandas, there would be no way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: I am worried it is bug, so it is really problem :( And I see another problem - if you change your code  for some reason, in oldier version if failed again for another bug or not implemented feature :(

Comment: Yeah I see your point. Well, then I'll just go back to working on my personal pc, unfortunately there is not really another way.

Comment: Unfortunately :(